Laravel Filament not working well on localhost
I'm attempting to access Laravel Filament on localhost, but it's not working. When I try to access http://localhost/public/admin, I receive the following error:

The POST method is not supported for this route: admin/login.
Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

However, when I use php artisan serve, everything works perfectly. This is a fresh installation and I haven't modified anything. As mentioned, when I run php artisan serve, everything functions as expected.

public/ should not appear in urls, it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your project. Create a vhost for your project or keep on using php artisan serve

How will then I be able to deploy my project on a live server? Will I be using artisan serve on a live server?

No php artisan serve on your production server. You create a vhost and set its DocumentRoot as mentioned.

I think you must config DocumentRoot target to public/
I ussually develop by Dockerfile and config DocumentRoot:
Apache2:
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/app/public

<Directory "/var/www/app/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Nginx:
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/app/public;

index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
}

Another way that I often use but I think it is not recommended is to create a .htaccess file in the root directory.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

The .htaccess file with this content will navigate to your public directory
Hope it will help you
